# "var" naming of variables

Tags: java, naming-conventions, var

Reading some java sources I often found variable naming like "va1", "var2", "var3" and so on. What is the purpose for such naming?

Example:

```
public int read(char[] var1, int var2, int var3) throws IOException {
    int var4 = var2;
    int var5 = var3;
    Object var6 = this.lock;
```

Comment: The purpose is to clearly show how lazy and unimaginative the developer is :-) Honestly, there is *no* reason why variables should ever be named like this is decent code.

Comment: This looks like the work of a decompiler or other automatic tool that is unable to infer useful names. Or maybe even a deliberate attempt to obfuscate. The quality of your variable names decide whether your code becomes nice and self-documenting or a source of constant confusion that leads to bugs due to misunderstandings.

Comment: This code was obtained using intellij idea decompiler, so maybe it was the cause.

Answer (score 2):

There are no *reasons* for that. Instead, there may be *causes* that lead to this kind of naming. As others have pointed out, that may be due to one of at least 3 points:

1. Lazy developers
2. Automatic code generation
3. Voluntary code obfuscation (yes, people do this)

Pointless to mention that this is a really bad practice because, as you can see, the code is very unclear and difficult to read and that may easily generate logic errors. And when that happens and you have to find them, good luck.